# Probability mass function of minimum number of balls drawn from an urn

Tags: probability

The problem is : Suppose you have an urn with $r \in \mathbb{N}$ many red balls and $b \in \mathbb{N}$ many black balls. All balls of same colour look identical. Suppose you sample uniformly from this urn with replacement. Let N be the minimum number of balls needed to see balls of all colours. Find the pmf of $N$.

Let $N$ be the random variable of minimum number of balls needed to see balls of all colours. Then $p_N(x)=P(N = x)$. Here, we have $x-1$ many balls of same colour appearing before the $x^{\text{th}}$ ball is of different colour. If the first $x-1$ balls are of colour red, then there are $r^{n-1}$ many ways of it happening multiplied by $b$ ways of the $x^{\text{th}}$ ball being blue. Similarly, if the first $x-1$ balls are blue and the last ball is red, total number of ways are $b^{n-1}r$. So $p_N(x) = P[N=x] = \dfrac{r^{n-1}b+b^{n-1}r}{(r+b)^n}$. It can be seen that $$\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{r^{n-1}b+b^{n-1}r}{(r+b)^n} = \dfrac{r}{r+b} + \dfrac{b}{b+r} = 1$$ so it is a valid pmf.

Is this solution correct? I am new to probability mass function and other topics so I am unsure whether this solution is correct or not. I would appreciate few resources with which I can learn probability mass function.

Comment: Your solution is okay except that your switching between $x$ and $n$ is confusing. If I were you then I would change every occurrence of $x$ in your question into an occurrence of $n$.

Comment: @drhab Oops my bad. Sorry for that